# Proteção CRSF ao excluir múltiplos itens AJAX

Tags: php, javascript

Quando eu uso um único form (cadastro, por exemplo), eu crio um **token** **e uma session** para "controlar" que o request só será executada da página de origem. mas quando eu possuo vários botões, que serão chamados via AJAX, qual a melhor forma de contornar isso? é viável criar centenas de sessions para cada token? nesse tipo de aplicação é usado `<form>` ou links `<a>` mesmo?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses botões serão executados via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

A proteção de `CSSF` é para impedir que outro website e outro software, como aplicativos para celulares, consigam fazer uma requisição *em nome do usuário*, **em resumo**.

Por exemplo:

```
$.post("https://twitter.com/i/tweet/like", { 
       authenticity_token: "411e9d041eb283109fdde6f4357ec128d3e47bec", 
       id: "815385473703022593",
       tweet_stat_count: "1998"
  });
```

Se não houvesse o `authenticity_token` (que é o CSRF Token do Twitter) seria possível incluir isto num website e todos que acessarem iriam curtir a publicação [815385473703022593](https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/814155499935596545). A presença do `authenticity_token` é quem impede isso, porque ele é um número aleatório.

O CSRF Token foi criado para impedir que isso funcione...

```
$.post("https://twitter.com/i/tweet/like", {id: "815385473703022593", tweet_stat_count: "1998" });
```

... por exemplo, **IGNORANDO QUE EXISTA O CORS**.

Entretanto, todas as requisições, de curtidas, de retweet, de remoção de tweet (...), de um mesmo usuário, usam um mesmo `token` e não faz sentido possuir um token diferente por botão, isso é insano.

Você não precisa manter em sessão, embora eu que recomende, você pode manter em `cookie` em texto plano. O Instagram faz isso, o *cookie* de nome `csfrtoken` é quem válida o *header* de nome `x-csrftoken`, *se mudar o header e cookie para `1` ele será válido.*

Enfim, use apenas um `token` para todos os botões, isso é suficiente. ;)